# Unresponsiveness to cues

Tags: cognitive-science, social-cues

Assuming a child or person is not visually impaired or deaf, and is not unwilling to respond, for whatever reason, then what kind of medical conditions could be responsible for making such person unresponsive to visual and sound cues?

Thanks.